# Force grid lines to update when range changes in Core-Plot scatter plot on iOS

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a CPTXYGraph with a CPTScatterPlot, which I update with new data using [graph reloadData]. I also set the ranges based on the data. My problem is that though the axes update fine when the range changes, the gridlines do not, so I end up with this http://inky.ws/g/hw (no grid lines at the end of the x-axis).

I set axis.gridLinesRange = nil, and I tried re-setting all the gridline properties when updating ranges, to no avail.

To clarify, the original plot looks fine, but when I update with a bigger data set, the grid lines are missing in the added range.

Comment: Are you changing the overall size of the graph or just the plot ranges?

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue and used the following workaround: calculate new bounds of your values and replace the default plot space range with a new one using the plotRangeWithLocation:length: convenience method.

Not very satisfying performance-wise and conceptually (feels a bit like doing the job of the framework) but it worked for me.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat([valuesMin floatValue]) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([valuesMax floatValue]-[valuesMin floatValue])];


CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;    
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

float amplitude = ([valuesMax floatValue]-[valuesMin floatValue]);
NSDecimal intervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(100);
y.majorIntervalLength = intervalLength;
```

Comment: This is the correct way to update the plot ranges--you always have to create a new range. If you retrieve the existing plot range and change it in place, the graph does not get notified of the change.

Comment: That's why the ranges are copy properties. If you'd like to see it changed, make an enhancement request on the Core Plot issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list

Comment: Ok, so this solves the problem, thanks a bunch! I'd vote you up, but it appears I lack reputation.